# DatagridView picture image to PictureBox1 in C#

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, picturebox

Can you please help me solve my problem. I have a Datagridview and a picturebox.. I already have my database connected to my datagridview when form loads.. When I select a row in it I should get the Image file from database to the PictureBox1. How do i do that? I still can't post pictures .. Please can anyone help me? Thank you..

```
    private void ListView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                idnum.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                CmbPosition.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                TxtFirstName.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                TxtMiddleName.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                TxtLastName.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                CmbYearLevel.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                CmbCourse.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                TxtSchoolYear.Text = ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();

                //Classes.MainFormClass ret = new Classes.MainFormClass();
                //ret.retPic();

                BtnAdd.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ClearData();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

for now, i have that code, when i click a row in the datagridview, it gets information from the database and shows in the controls = idnum.Text, CmbPosition.Text, etc... But the image does not show in Picturebox1.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer now.

```
    PicBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ListView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString(), true);
```

Just have to put that code inside my if statement. Hope this helps to anyone who has same problem as me.